# Sum Calculation in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, sum

Say I have two 'tables' in Prolog, e.g.:

```
item_value('Chair', 50).          
item_value('Table', 100).        
item_value('Plant', 75).
```

And another one:

```
shopping_cart('Max', ['Chair', 'Chair', 'Table']).            
shopping_cart('Sam', ['Plant', 'Table']).
```

I now want to write a predicate that calculates the sum of the items inside the shopping cart, something like **total_sum(Person, Sum)**

How would i do this? I can't wrap my head around coding this in Prolog.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here's a hint... If you have a list of items, `Items`, and you want to add up their values, you can do it easily with `findall(Cost, (member(Item, Items), item_value(Item, Cost)), Costs).` then add them up, `sumlist(Costs, TotalCost).`. If you can't use `findall/3` or `sumlist/2` (seems to be a favorite constraint among Prolog homework assignments), then write a recursive predicate to do it.

Comment: Think of Prolog as being like a query language. If you query, `item_value(Item, Cost).` it will yield each `Item` and `Cost` that is in your data. Another fundamental aspect of Prolog is handling lists. If you aren't comfortable handling lists, I'd suggest a good text book, tutorial, or look at a bunch of example problems such as [99 Prolog Problems](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2009s2/prolog/problemas/). That's all I can give you in this context. This isn't a free, personalized language tutorial site. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
item_value('Chair', 50).          
item_value('Table', 100).        
item_value('Plant', 75).

shopping_cart('Max', ['Chair', 'Chair', 'Table']).            
shopping_cart('Sam', ['Plant', 'Table']).

total_sum(Person, Sum) :-
    shopping_cart(Person, ItemList),
    maplist(item_value, ItemList, CostList),
    foldl(plus, CostList, 0, Sum).
```